# Como puxar informações do banco de dados em um código php

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, eu tenho um código em PHP, e dentro dele gostaria de puxar informações.

```
@$host = "23.98.102.87";
@$port = "9498";
```

Onde tem o s número é onde eu queria puxar os dados, eu já fiz o select, mas gostaria de saber, como eu poderia puxar informações do banco dentro de um php. Por exemplo, eu tenho um banco de dados, onde já tem esses ip e número, e queria que viesse de lá, e não que eu mudasse manualmente.

Bom, eu tenho um código imenso, e dá erros usando o **echo**.

Código:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$radios1_3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM radios ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 300") or die(mysql_error());
$linha = mysql_fetch_array($radios1_3);
echo "
@$host = " . $linha["sc"] . ";
@$port = " . $linha["sc2"] . ";
@$listenlink = 'http://23.238.135.80:9998/listen.pls';  //make link to stream
@$fp = fsockopen($host, $port); //open connection
if(!$fp) {
@$success=2;  //se-t if no connection
}
if(@$success!=2){ //if connection
@fputs($fp,"GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: XML Getter (Mozilla Compatible)\r\n\r\n"); //get 7.html
while(!feof($fp)) {
@$pg .= fgets($fp, 1000);
}
@fclose($fp); //close connection
@$paage = ereg_replace(".*<font class=default>Stream Title: </font></td><td><font class=default><b>", "", $pg); //extract data
@$paage = ereg_replace("</b></td></tr><tr><td width=100 nowrap>.*", "", $paage); //extract data
@$pge = ereg_replace(".*<font class=default>Stream Genre: </font></td><td><font class=default><b>", "", $pg); //extract data
@$pge = ereg_replace("</b></td></tr><tr><td width=100 nowrap>.*", "", $pge); //extract data
@$pe = ereg_replace(".*<font class=default>Stream Genre: </font></td><td><font class=default><b>", "", $pg); //extract data
@$pe = ereg_replace("</b></td></tr><tr><td width=100 nowrap>.*", "", $pe); //extract data
@$musica = ereg_replace(".*com:<font class=default>Current Song: </font></td><td><font class=default><b>", "", $pg); //extract data
@$musica = ereg_replace("</b></td></tr></table>.*", "", $musica); //extract data
@$numbers = explode(",",$paage); //extract data
@$servertitle=$numbers[0]; //set variable
@$connected=$numbers[4]; //set variable
}
@$fp2 = fsockopen("$host", $port); //open connection
if(!$fp2) {
@$success2=2;  //se-t if no connection
}
if(@$success2!=2){ //if connection
fputs($fp2,"GET /7.html HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: XML Getter (Mozilla Compatible)\r\n\r\n"); //get 7.html
while(!feof($fp2)) {
@$pg2 .= fgets($fp2, 1000);
}
fclose($fp2); //close connection
@$pag = ereg_replace(".*<body>", "", $pg2); //extract data
@$pag = ereg_replace("</body>.*", ",", $pag); //extract data
@$numbers = explode(",",$pag); //extract data
$currentlisteners=$numbers[0]; //set variable
}
// ATUALIZADOR
if(@$_GET['ver'] == "dj"){
echo"$paage";
}
if(@$_GET['ver'] == "ouvintes"){
echo $currentlisteners;
}
if(@$_GET['ver'] == "musica"){
echo "$musica";
}
if(@$_GET['ver'] == "programa"){
echo"$pge";
}
if(@$_GET['ver'] == "imgloc"){
echo'<div id="boneco" style="background:url(https://www.habbo.com.br/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?img_format=gif&user='.$paage.'&action=std&direction=2&head_direction=2&gesture=spk&size=b);"></div>';
}
";
// ATUALIZADOR
?>
```

Comment: Que erro aparece? ou o que não acontece?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7lrnbi

Comment: So esse erro aparece? Qual é a linha 14, poderia evidenciar ela.

Comment: Sim, quando eu apago a linha desse erro, ainda continua na mesma linha, mesmo a parte debaixo substituindo.

Comment: pq precisa do `echo`, precisa separa as instruções das saidas de texto.

Answer (score 1):

As modificações que sugiro são, remover o echo e seu fechamento

```
$linha = mysql_fetch_array($radios1_3);
echo "

//Muito código depois...

if(@$_GET['ver'] == "imgloc"){
echo'<div id="boneco" style="background:url(https://www.habbo.com.br/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?img_format=gif&user='.$paage.'&action=std&direction=2&head_direction=2&gesture=spk&size=b);"></div>';
}
"; //<---- Fim do echo
```

Remover todas as `@` pois elas ocultam os erros/warning eles devem ser tratados, as vezes so `isset` já resolve.

Se pega apenas o primeiro registro, pode deixar o limit em 1 no lugar de 300

```
$radios1_3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM radios ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 300") or die(mysql_error());
$linha = mysql_fetch_array($radios1_3);
```

Todas as modificações:

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $radios1_3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM radios ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
    $linha = mysql_fetch_array($radios1_3);
    $host =  $linha["sc"];
    $port =  $linha["sc2"];
    $listenlink = 'http://23.238.135.80:9998/listen.pls';  //make link to stream
    $fp = fsockopen($host, $port); //open connection
    if(!$fp) {
        $success=2;  //se-t if no connection
    }

    if($success!=2){ //if connection
        fputs($fp,"GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: XML Getter (Mozilla Compatible)\r\n\r\n"); //get 7.html
        while(!feof($fp)) {
            $pg .= fgets($fp, 1000);
        }
        fclose($fp); //close connection
        $paage = ereg_replace(".*<font class=default>Stream Title: </font></td><td><font class=default><b>", "", $pg);
        $paage = ereg_replace("</b></td></tr><tr><td width=100 nowrap>.*", "", $paage);
        $pge = ereg_replace(".*<font class=default>Stream Genre: </font></td><td><font class=default><b>", "", $pg);
        $pge = ereg_replace("</b></td></tr><tr><td width=100 nowrap>.*", "", $pge);
        $pe = ereg_replace(".*<font class=default>Stream Genre: </font></td><td><font class=default><b>", "", $pg);
        $pe = ereg_replace("</b></td></tr><tr><td width=100 nowrap>.*", "", $pe);
        $musica = ereg_replace(".*com:<font class=default>Current Song: </font></td><td><font class=default><b>", "", $pg);
        $musica = ereg_replace("</b></td></tr></table>.*", "", $musica);
        $numbers = explode(",",$paage); //extract data
        $servertitle=$numbers[0]; //set variable
        $connected=$numbers[4]; //set variable
    }

    $fp2 = fsockopen("$host", $port); //open connection
    if(!$fp2) {
        $success2=2;  //se-t if no connection
    }

    if($success2!=2){ //if connection
        fputs($fp2,"GET /7.html HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: XML Getter (Mozilla Compatible)\r\n\r\n"); //get 7.html
        while(!feof($fp2)) {
            $pg2 .= fgets($fp2, 1000);
        }
        fclose($fp2); //close connection
        $pag = ereg_replace(".*<body>", "", $pg2);
        $pag = ereg_replace("</body>.*", ",", $pag);
        $numbers = explode(",",$pag);
        $currentlisteners=$numbers[0];
    }
    // ATUALIZADOR
    if(isset($_GET['ver'])){
        if($_GET['ver'] == "dj"){
            echo $paage;
        }

        if($_GET['ver'] == "ouvintes"){
            echo $currentlisteners;
        }

        if($_GET['ver'] == "musica"){
            echo $musica;
        }

        if($_GET['ver'] == "programa"){
            echo $pge;
        }

        if($_GET['ver'] == "imgloc"){
            echo'<div id="boneco" style="background:url(https://www.habbo.com.br/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?img_format=gif&user='.$paage.'&action=std&direction=2&head_direction=2&gesture=spk&size=b);"></div>';
        }
    }   
    // ATUALIZADOR
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você já possui o select, basta fazer o seguinte:

```
$linha = mysql_fetch_array($seu_select);
echo "@$host = " . $linha["ip"] . "; @$port = " . $linha["porta"];
```

Assumindo que esteja usando o mysql_query, e não PDO ou MySQLi, caso esteja usando um dos dois me fale.

Comment: Olá, tá dando erro com o echo, não deu erro na parte de puxar os dados, mas em outra coisa deu, poderia me ajudar a resolver? Postei o código na edição da minha pergunta. Obrigado.

Comment: Você precisa concertar seu echo. Percebe que ele é utilizado com aspas duplas, então você não pode colocar outra aspas duplas dentro dele. Para isso você teria que usar caractere de escape '\' (contra-barra) antes da aspas que deseja imprimir.